# Change directory to the location of the operating script

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

So, I can find out the directory of the script with

```
function Get-ScriptDirectory { Split-Path -parent $PSCommandPath }
```

But I can't manage to change the directory to the folder, where the script is saved. For example

```
cd d:\MyScripts\
```

So something like

```
cd function Get-ScriptDirectory { Split-Path -parent $PSCommandPath }
```

doesn't work.

And sorry if that is a common and dumb question, but I'm new in powershell and I searched and tried a lot before posting here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below. You can include the code sample in your script. Then if you are running the script from other location (by means of fully qualifying path name to the script);  `$MyInvocation` will pickup the invocation location.

From [Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx)

> ```
> $MyInvocation
>    Contains an information about the current command, such as the name, 
>    parameters, parameter values, and information about how the command was
>    started, called, or "invoked," such as the name of the script that called
>    the current command.
> ```

Code Sample

```
$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$dir = Split-Path $scriptpath
cd $dir
```